# onTextContextMenuItem not called for EditText on Xiaomi devices

Tags: android

I have a class that inherits from EditText. I override the behavior of the onTextContextMenuItem to handle clicks to the edit text context menu (i.e. menu that has cut, paste, copy).

On most devices, this callback is called when a user selects one of those options:

```
// id can be android.R.id.paste, android.R.id.copy, etc.
@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id)
```

Except on Xiaomi devices. It seems they override the context menu and don't bother to call the regular methods.

Does anyone know how to capture these events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a hack around the fact that Xiaomi devices do not properly call onTextContextMenuItem. The general gist is we want to add a TextWatcher to the EditText:

```
this.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // on non-Xiaomi devices this will be true
    if(sOnTextContextMenuItemWorks) {
      return;
    }

    // do the stuff you want to do
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
});
```

You can use a static boolean sOnTextContextMenuItemWorks to avoid running this code on non-Xiaomi devices. You initialize the value of sOnTextContextMenuItemWorks to false and then in onTextContextMenuItem (which won't be called on Xiaomi devices), you set the value of sOnTextContextMenuItemWorks to true.

```
@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
  sOnTextContextMenuItemWorks = true;

  // do the stuff you want to do
}
```

You won't catch copies, but you'll know when there is a paste or cut.

If any Xiaomi engineers read this, please just call onTextContextMenuItem!!!